# finding number of trailing zeroes in a number

Tags: c++

I wanted to find the number of trailing zeroes in a number, so i made the following code. It worked fine for certain numbers but for bigger numbers it started showing anomaly. Like when i input the number"12345678" it show zero 0`s which is correct but when i input "123456789" it shows one zero, what can be the possible mistake in my code???

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n = 0;
float s;
cin>>s; //the number to be given as input
for(int j = 0;j <100;j++){

 s = s/10;
if(s == floor(s)){
n++;
}else{

break;
}
}
cout<<n<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW `n` is uninitialized.

Comment: If I were you I would read the number into a `std::string` and count the zeros starting at the end of the string.

Comment: `float` has limited precision. You are likely dropping the last digit. How many 0 does the number 1.2345678E7 have?

Comment: Trailing zeros are only meaningful for integer numbers. So use integer instead of float. And use `if (s%10)` instead of your current solution.

Comment: what is wrong with code @NathanOliver

Comment: thanks @FrançoisAndrieux i just got to know that float datatype has only 7 digits of precision ,while using double which has 15 digits of precision gives the right answer

Comment: thanks for your help @geza

Comment: @vaibnak Don't use `double` or `float`.  They will burn you.  Use integer types instead or better yet use a `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point numbers have a limited precision. Usually, float is a 32-bit number, double is a 64-bit one. Float can store integer numbers precisely if the number is less than or equal to 16777216 (it is 2^24).

So, when 123456789 is read into a float variable, will have a different value, it becomes 123456792. At this point, there is no rationale to count trailing zeros.

Double can store integer numbers precisely if it is less than or equal to 9007199254740992 (2^53).

An `unsigned long long int` can store integer numbers less than 2^64. If you choose this way, use this condition for checking trailing zero: `if (number%10==0)`

If you only want to count trailing zeros, and that's all, then use `std::string` instead. This way you can handle as big numbers as you like.